# Rescue Exceptions. Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick, rescue

I'm trying to catch an exception in a view. I use rgmagick in my .html.erb file:

```
<%= f.label :image, "image file" %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

I'm trying to catch the exception when the file is not right by this way but it's not right :S

```
<% begin %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image, "image file" %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% rescue %>
  <% puts 'error' %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea??
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might not fully understand MVC. Your view should not be rescuing from exceptions (that's what your controller or model should be doing). If this pattern makes sense to you, then simply add any exceptions you encounter as string messages to your ActiveRecord model errors parameter in your controller or model. Lastly, use a gem when doing image processing such as:

- [Attached](https://github.com/ksylvest/attached)
- [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)
- [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)
- [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/)

If you have never done image processing in Rails before, I'd recommend check:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads